# How to escape SQL keywords in JPAQL

Tags: java, sql, jpa, escaping, keyword

I would like to have an entity named "GROUP" in my JPA setup. Now I get problems when I try to perform JPA queries, like "select count(group_.id) from Group group_".

JPA thinks this is a misplaced GROUP BY attempt and complains. Is there a way I can escape "Group", or do I have to rename my table?

Thx!

Comment: Seems this is impossible, reserved words can't be used that way in JPA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**please don't do it!**

rename your table to something else, you'll thank me in the long run.  Don't use any reserved words for table or column names!

name it something like EmployeeGroup, JobGroup or ObjectGroup, etc...